# Matrix series convergence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, power-series, taylor-expansion

Suppose we have the Maclaurin series of a function $f$, and it converges in a radius $R$. Then suppose we define a matrix argument to the function in a similar manner to the exponential definition of a matrix. Do all those series converge respectively in the same radius $R$ for all matrices?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function And if you can get a hand on Gantmacher's *"Matrix theory"* or Higham's *"Functions of Matrices"*, have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the norm you are using for measuring the convergence of the matrix power series. If you take a matrix norm which is submultiplicative, i.e. $||AB||\leq||A||\cdot||B||$, then if the real or complex power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ has radius of convergence $R$, then the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n A^n$ converges, if $A$ is a matrix with $||A||<R$.
(See also the wikipedia article that has been recommended in a comment)

However, if you take a matrix norm that is not submultiplicative, the statement turns wrong. For instance, take the matrix norm
$$
||A||_\infty:=\max_{i,j}|A_{i,j}|,
$$
where $A_{i,j}$ denotes the entry of $A$ in row $i$ and column $j$. Consider $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & t\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
for fixed $t\in\mathbb R$. Then $||A||_\infty=|t|$, but since $A^n=0$ for $n>1$, the series 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nA^n=a_0I+a_1A
$$
converges, no matter what the radius of convergence of the corresponding real/complex power series is.